# Логическое И &&

Tags: c++

Всем привет! В чём разница между `if (root->left && root->right == nullptr)` и  `if (root->left == nullptr && root->right == nullptr)`. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `root->left` - это тоже что и `root->left != nullptr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`root->left` — это любое значение кроме `nullptr`.

Comment: А вдруг там не указатель?)

Comment: Любое значение отличное от нуля будет правильнее.